# Visual Studio 2010 - IDE command to find extension method namespace?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide, extension-methods

I make heavy use of  + <.> to find the namespace of types and have VS.NET import those types into my class files. Similar to that, suppose I have a DateTime extension method called `ToWebsiteString()`. I'd like to be able to type `myDateTime.ToWebsiteString`, and then hit the equivalent of  + <.> and have the IDE display a list of all available namespaces with that extension method, so that I can simply select the namespace and have VS.NET import it into the class file that I'm working in. Does that already exist?

If not, what is the most productive way you've found to import your extension method namespaces?

Edit:
Are there any free solutions for this?

Edit: 
Other than the pay for Resharper, it doesn't appear that there are any free solutions for this, so I've closed this question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) can do this for you.

Type `myDateTime.ToWebsiteString`, hit `Alt+Enter` and Resharper will show a list of namespaces to select from.

Comment: Good to know, seems like Resharper is a great tool. I'll keep it in mind but I'm looking for something that would be free.

Comment: I can't do any development without Resharper anymore. All the developer I know who tried Resharper once could not continue without it. It makes coding a lot more efficient.

Comment: Maybe I should check it out. I'm always slow to part with my money

Comment: Resharper has consistently slowed my IDE down to a crawl, not worth it. Some swear by it though, YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

If you type/select the extension method, like:

```
Html.ActionLink
```

Then hit F12 with the cursor inside the extension method name, Visual Studio will take you to the class (and namespace) that adds that Extension Method, even if it's buried in some DLL somewhere (it shows you the public method stubs). Good enough, works without Resharper.